# AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.util._pywrap_checkpoint_reader.C' object has no attribute 'endswith'

Tags: python-3.x, file, directory, tensorflow2.0, recurrent-neural-network

trying to run this code and i keep getting this error about no endwith
this is the code.

```
# Directory where the checkpoints will be saved
checkpoint_dir = "./training_checkpoints"
# Name of the checkpoint files
checkpoint_prefix = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "ckpt_{epoch}")

checkpoint_callback=tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=checkpoint_prefix,
    save_weights_only=True
)

checkpoint_num = 10
model.load_weights(tf.train.load_checkpoint('./training_checkpoints/ckpt_' + str(checkpoint_num)))
model.build(tf.TensorShape([1, None]))
```

and the error keeps coming up as

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-0b9ba2931637> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 checkpoint_num = 10
----> 2 model.load_weights(tf.train.load_checkpoint('./training_checkpoints/ckpt_' + str(checkpoint_num)))
      3 model.build(tf.TensorShape([1, None]))

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/saving/legacy/saving_utils.py in is_hdf5_filepath(filepath)
    366 def is_hdf5_filepath(filepath):
    367     return (
--> 368         filepath.endswith(".h5")
    369         or filepath.endswith(".keras")
    370         or filepath.endswith(".hdf5")

AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.util._pywrap_checkpoint_reader.C' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

i have tried to change the "checkpoint_dir" value but the problem persists. I